# Unix command to join multiple lines into one line

Tags: unix

I have a file, test.txt

```
outputa
outputb
outputc
outputa
outputb
outputc
```

I need output like this:

```
outputaoutputboutputc 
outputaoututboutputc
```

Lines should be broken at each occurence of outputa.

Comment: a java program will also help

Comment: Have you attempted anything?  Please include that in the question.  You could use `xargs` for it.

Comment: The breaking requirement is not clear for me. Do you want something like `tr -d "\n" < test.txt | sed 's/outputa/\n&/g;$s/$/\n/'`?

Comment: Thank you ! this worked :) can you please elaborate what the sed part did

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably not exactly what you want, but this should get you started:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class FileTransformer {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        String s1 = readFile("test.txt");
        s1 = transform(s1, args[0]);
        writeFile(s1);
    }

    private static String readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)));
    }

    private static String transform(String input, String elementToStartNewLine) {
        return input.replace("\n", "").replace(elementToStartNewLine, "\n" + elementToStartNewLine);
    }

    private static void writeFile(String content) throws IOException {
        Files.write(Paths.get("output.txt"), content.getBytes());
    }
}
```

Usage: java FileTransformer outputa

Comment: Great, but what if the third line is not always the same? Which I guess will *always* be the case?

Comment: @Ashwini I believe it should do what you want now :)

Comment: Yes I got my answer ! Thankyou

Comment: tr -d "\n" < test.txt | sed 's/outputa/\n&/g;$s/$/\n/'  worked ! Thanks

Comment: Hi @Ahswini could you click accept on my answer, if that's okay for you? :)